# Opening SSRS Report in new window

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssrs-2008-r2

I created a simple ASP.NET page using C# where a user enters a parameter, clicks on a button and an SSRS report is run and displayed within the webpage.  However, i would like the report to open in a new window instead of embedded in the ASPX page.

Here is my current code now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string AccountNumber = AcctNo.Text;
            ReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(@"http://johnssrsd04/ReportServer_SSRS2008DEV01");
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Client Metrics POC/Reports/ClientMetricsDownload_POC";
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
            ReportParameter[] reportParameterCollection = new ReportParameter[1]; //Array size describes the number of paramaters.
            reportParameterCollection[0] = new ReportParameter();
            reportParameterCollection[0].Name = "paraAcctNo"; //Give Your Parameter Name
            reportParameterCollection[0].Values.Add(AccountNumber); //Pass Parametrs's value here.
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameterCollection);
            ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change it to open the SSRS report in an new window?

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service and is not meant for delivering complete solutions. Users are expected to show some effort and code whilst SO is here to help you solve specific programming problems along the way. Have you tried anything to make it work like that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using JavaScript:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" OnClientClick="openReport();"  Text="Open Report" />

<script>
    function openReport() {
        window.open("yourReportPage.aspx");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Change your button click code to the Load event.